# Postgresql use alternative character instead of quote for column and table names

Tags: c#, postgresql

Is it possible to use different character instead of " for PostgreSQL table and column names?

Something like:

```
select [TableID], [TableColumn] from [TableName]
```

or

```
select 'TableID', 'TableColumn' from 'TableName'
```

instead of:

```
select "TableID", "TableColumn" from "TableName"
```

I use C# and each time I need to replace `"` with `""` when I paste SQL into a C# string and than back `""` to `"` when I copy C# string to SQL manager.

I wonder is there is anything to use instead of `"` to quote the names in PostgreSQL.

CamelCase in PostgreSQL require names to be quoted, in other case the names will be automatically lower cased - what I try to avoid.

And yes, I need a camel case table and column names in PostgreSQL to auto map them to C# property names.

Comment: Perhaps the mapping function can do the CamelCase <-> underscore conversion? NHibernate calls this "access strategies".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The only allowed quote character for object names is the double quote (as required by the SQL standard).

Comment: The manual supports this (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and offers no alternative quoting schemes for identifiers.

Comment: It's pitty :(
The only choose - stored procedures. In PostgreSQL SPs are much more verbose than in MS SQL IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You can always try using escape characters.

```
string sql = "select \"TableID\", \"TableColumn\" from \"TableName\"";
```

This should give you the ability to both keep the double quotes, and add the sql to a string at the same time.

But honestly, unless it's a column name WITH a space. I almost never use the quotes for anything, and any spaces I may hit, I use underscores.  So my sql usually looks like;

```
string sql = "SELECT table_id, table_column FROM table_name";
```